# modifiers for multiple objects in java

Tags: java, modifier

it is possible to do something like this in java?

```
static public final {
    String A = "a...";
    int B = 3;
    boolean C = true;
}
```

thanks!

EDIT: sorry i made a mistake in my example.. I don't need only Strings..

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of strings?

Comment: that sort-of looks like a static initializer...sort-of

Comment: Something like what? What is that code block supposed to represent?

Comment: @mdm, no I don't think he's trying to do that. Notice how his block (not type) is declared static, public and final.

Answer (score 7):

Wrong Syntax. But you can do it like this:

```
public static final String A = "a...", B = "b...", C = "c...";
```

Or, closer to your version (white space is irrelevant in Java):

```
public static final String
   A = "a...",
   B = "b...",
   C = "c...";
```

---

For reference, here's the [official grammar for Field Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#40898) from the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html):

```
FieldDeclaration:
    FieldModifiersopt Type VariableDeclarators ; # one variable type only

VariableDeclarators:
    VariableDeclarator
    VariableDeclarators , VariableDeclarator     # one or more variables

VariableDeclarator:
    VariableDeclaratorId
    VariableDeclaratorId = VariableInitializer

VariableDeclaratorId:
    Identifier
    VariableDeclaratorId [ ]

VariableInitializer:
    Expression
    ArrayInitializer
```

So as you can see (from my comments) you can declare multiple fields of the same type with common modifiers, but you can't mix types.

Comment: Works, but only if the variables all have the same type. And it's ugly.

Comment: @marzapower I know, but the question was whether one *can* do it, not whether one *should* do it :-)

Comment: +1 it's not clear code IMO to initialize variables like this; but as stated above the question was whether it's possible.

Comment: sorry but I have not explained well my example, now I edited it

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean like?

```
public interface Constants {
    String A = "a...";
    String B = "b...";
    String C = "c...";
}
```

In your code you can use a static import.

```
import static Constants.*;

System.out.println(A);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.
Usually, smart auto complete in a preferred IDE helps a bit.
E.g. in the netbeans, "Psfs" + tab expands to public static final String

Answer (score 0):

No. At the moment no version of Java will permit you to do that.

Even if it would be really useful, I admit.

Comment: But not with this syntax, because that would be very confusing with regard to static initializer blocks: `static { ... }`.

Comment: Obviously. I mean, it would really be useful to define a (large) group of variable that share the same modifiers ... even with a slight different structure.

Answer (score 0):

You may declare a static block and in that static block create variables:

```
public class TestS {
    static {
        String  a = "a...";
        int     b = 3;
        boolean c = true;
    }
```

But once you leave the scope of that static block, you wouldn't be able to reference `a`, `b`, or `c`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(a); // won't compile
    }
}
```

In main, `a` cannot be resolved to a variable.